# Google analytics A/B testing

Tags: javascript, testing, google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to track which of two links on a page a user clicks more. Each has its own ID, but they are going to the same landing page. I would prefer not to go through an AB testing software if I can do this somehow with Google Analytics and some javascript.

Comment: You can use [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) and fire a different event for each link.

Comment: .. or the same event with a different action or label. In any case comparing two links on the same page would never require A/B testing software, which would be used for testing different versions (i.e. color, format) of the same link.

Comment: Event tracking worked very well, thank you! I ended up doing one event with 2 different actions. Thanks for the links and help